# java Memory Leaks and grow Surviving Generations

Tags: java, netbeans, memory-leaks, profiler

i have problem with my project that need send many of request to server

problem is continues growing Surviving Generations ..

i develop my project with Netbeans IDE and i am using NetBeans Profiler to detect a Memory Leak .

i created a class for testing:

**test class**

```
public class test {

    public test(String url) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        client.execute(request);
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    }

}
```

**main class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
            new test("http://foo.dev/article?id="+i);
        }
    }
}
```

**NetBeans Profiler results:**

**Surviving Generations**
 [image: Generations Result]
**Heap Result**

[image: Heap Result]

***netbeans site***:

> Typically, the Surviving Generations value starts to grow during an
>   application's startup, but after some time it should reach some stable
>   limit and level off. When this happens it indicates that no objects
>   are being created continuously and leaking. If the Surviving
>   Generations line continues to grow all the time (regardless of how
>   quickly), then the application is most likely leaking.

**my question** is why Surviving Generations line continues to grow and What is the cause in my Code ?

any help please...

Comment: I had the some observation in a program. Some thoughts:  1.In your program: CloseableHttpClient and HttpGet are from Apache, right? So it is really hard to know if the phenomena is caused by those classes without detailed analysis 2. "Typically" does not mean "for sure", right? 3. is client.execute non-blocking? 4. the behavior might depend on the other endpoint of the network ... Can you modify the example to be independent of another process?